# Python 4-channel video streaming program QThread speedup problem

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5, python-multiprocessing, qthread

It is a 4 channel video streaming program.

When running with QThread, if you stream 4 at the same time, the speed of the video will slow down and CPU usage will be 100%.

Can I change this to multiprocessing?

I want to speed up a 4 channel cctv program.

threadMode.py

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage
import cv2

class StreamingThread(QThread):
    changePixmap = pyqtSignal(QImage)

    def __init__(self):
        super(StreamingThread, self).__init__()
        self.running = True
        self.camUrl = None
        self.Qsize = None
        self.cap = None

    def setRtsp(self, camUrl):
        self.camUrl = camUrl

    def setSize(self, Qsize):
        self.Qsize = Qsize

    def run(self):
        try:
            self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.camUrl)
            if self.cap.isOpened():
                while self.running:
                    success, frame = self.cap.read()
                    if success:
                        rgbImage = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                        h, w, ch = rgbImage.shape
                        bytesPerLine = ch * w
                        convertToQtFormat = QImage(rgbImage.data, w, h, bytesPerLine, QImage.Format_RGB888)
                        p = convertToQtFormat.scaled(self.Qsize, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
                        self.changePixmap.emit(p)
            else:
                print("RTSP(RTMP) Video Streaming Fail")
                self.stop()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            self.stop()

    def stop(self):
        if self.running:
            self.running = False
            print("Streaming Stop")
        self.quit()
```

Main.py

```
def setChannel1(self):
    # Index 0: No Channel
    if self.chComboBox1.currentIndex() == 0:
        self.mStreamingThread1.terminate()
        sched = BackgroundScheduler()
        sched.add_job(self.clearChannel, 'date', run_date=datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=1), args=[self.cctvStreaming1])
        sched.start()
    else:
        ip, url, channel, boxId = self.findUrl(self.chComboBox1)
        if url != '' and channel != '':
            self.mStreamingThread1.terminate()
            self.mStreamingThread1.wait(1)
            self.mStreamingThread1.setRtsp(url)
            self.mStreamingThread1.setSize(self.cctvStreaming1.size())
            self.mStreamingThread1.changePixmap.connect(self.setImage1)
            self.mStreamingThread1.start()
            self.show()
            logger.info("Channel1 Streaming Success")

@pyqtSlot(QImage)
def setImage1(self, image):
    self.cctvStreaming1.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))
```

Comment: try add `time.sleep(.1)` after `self.changePixmap.emit(p)`

Comment: @eyllanesc 

Streaming screen freezes